# What is the quickest way to allow only integers (and restricting decimals) using HTML 5 and angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a text input, that will receive Ids. I would like to allow only integers.

The following code doesn't allow special characters but allows float/decimals:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control input-sm ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-number" name="idCliente" id="idCliente" placeholder="ID Cliente" ng-model="vm.idCliente" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-class="{'error': panelControl.idCliente.$error.pattern}">
```

what's the quickest way to restrict the decimals in the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add function that that will fire on keyup event and return true or false depending on results of this operation `num % 1 != 0`. Then you may just show warning by adding error class to your input and/or changing model value back to `null`.
**P.S.**
Using regex for such trivial purpose that's not good idea as well as from performance point of view.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?` to allow only numbers and desimal points in your `ng-pattern`

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-number" name="idCliente" id="idCliente" placeholder="ID Cliente" ng-model="vm.idCliente" ng-pattern="/[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?/"  >

</div>
```